# How do I make my code work with Generics?

Tags: java, list, class, generics, extends

I am currently learning about Generics, first I made the Class which makes a stackArrayList with Integers, after that I wanted it to be used by every Number so I did put the Number in everywhere in the Methods, it kind of worked but I think this is not quiet correct, my biggest Problem is that I cant use any addition or subtraction with the Class Number.

So I tried implement the N extends Number but that does not work either and with that I can't even put a Number which returns from the Method pop() inside of a variable, telling me that pop() must return an int then.

Can someone explain to me please, what I did there? I can grasp the logic behind of it but cannot understand it to the fullest.

```
public class StackArrayList<N extends Number> {

    private ArrayList<N> stackList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    
    public void push (N value) {
        if(value == null) {
            System.out.println("value null not allowed");
            return;
        }
        stackList.add(0,value);
        
    }
    public N pop() {
        N popInt = stackList.get(0);
        stackList.remove(0);
        return popInt;
    }
    public N addFirstTwo() {
        if(stackList.size()==1) {
            return stackList.get(0);
        }
        if (stackList.size() == 0) {return null;}
        
        
        if(stackList.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
            N summe;
            summe = 
            push(summe);
            return summe;
        }else if(stackList.get(0) instanceof Double){
            summe = pop().doubleValue()+pop().doubleValue();
            push(summe);
            return summe;
        }else if(stackList.get(0) instanceof Float){
            summe = pop().floatValue()+pop().floatValue();
            push(summe);
            return summe;
        }else if(stackList.get(0) instanceof Long){
            summe = pop().longValue()+pop().longValue();
            push(summe);
            return summe;
        }
        
        push(summe);
        return summe;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Number` does not support the `+` operator, even though all its implementations (`Double`, `Float` etc.) do support it.

What you can do is to define an inner interface to your class which exposes a `sum` method:

```
interface SumPerformer<N> {
    N sum(N n1, N n2);
}
```

Then, you will declare a field into your `StackArrayList<N extends Number>` class that holds an implementation of this interface:

```
private final SumPerformer<N> sumPerformer;
```

And so, you will use this implementation to return the sum of the two first numbers inside your `addFirstTwo()` method:

```
public N addFirstTwo() {
    if (stackList.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (stackList.size() == 1) {
        return stackList.get(0);
    }
    return sumPerformer.sum(stackList.get(0), stackList.get(1));
}
```

When it's time to initialize your `StackArrayList` with a concrete implementation of `Number`, you will simply pass it the implementation's `sum` by method reference:

```
    StackArrayList<Double> stackArrayListDoubles = new StackArrayList<>(Double::sum);
    StackArrayList<Long> stackArrayListLongs = new StackArrayList<>(Long::sum);
    StackArrayList<Integer> stackArrayListInts = new StackArrayList<>(Integer::sum);
```

---

Full code:

```
public static final class StackArrayList<N extends Number> {

    private final List<N> stackList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final SumPerformer<N> sumPerformer;

    public StackArrayList(SumPerformer<N> sumPerformer) {
        this.sumPerformer = sumPerformer;
    }

    public N pop() {
        N popInt = stackList.get(0);
        stackList.remove(0);
        return popInt;
    }

    public void push(N value) {
        if (value == null) {
            System.out.println("value null not allowed");
            return;
        }
        stackList.add(0, value);

    }

    public N addFirstTwo() {
        if (stackList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        if (stackList.size() == 1) {
            return stackList.get(0);
        }
        N sum = sumPerformer.sum(stackList.get(0), stackList.get(1));
        push(sum);
        return sum;
    }

    interface SumPerformer<N> {
        N sum(N n1, N n2);
    }

}
```

### Answers to the questions raised in the comments

> Doesn't the Variable need to be inside the <> ?

No. The `<>` (called diamond operator) is used to infer a specific type to a class which takes a "generic" type (you can read [more about generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)).

Before Java 8, you needed to specify the type both in the declaration and the instantiation of the variable. For example, the interface `List<T>` is implemented by the class `ArrayList<T>`.

Before Java 8, if you wanted a list of `Integer` you needed to do:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

After Java 8, you can simply state:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Indeed, the type `Integer` will be inferred to `ArrayList` by the declaration `List<Integer>`.

This is why, when I initialize my `StackArrayList<>`, I'm not passing `Double` to it because I already pass it to the declaration, so the variable already knows what is its type.

> shouldnt it just pass down the Number i initialize the Object with ?

Careful, you're mixing up stuff.
The reason why you shouldn't pass `Double` is explained above.
However, here I am doing something else.

If you check the new constructor of `StackArrayList`, I've added a member which is `private final SumPerformer<N> sumPerformer;`.

This member is `final`, it means it should be initialized when you initialize the class, and I do that by passing it into the constructor.

But so what am I passing to the constructor?
I am passing a *concrete implementation* of the abstract interface that I define.

Specifically, I have declared the interface `SumPerformer<N>` to expose only one method which is called `sum`, returns a `N` and takes in input two distinct `N`.

A concrete implementation of this interface, hence, should be a method with the same signature.

And this method, is the `sum()` method of all `Number` children (`Double`, `Integer`...)

If you go into the class `Double`, you will see that there is this method:

```
public static double sum(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The above method's signature matches with your interface when the type `N extends Number` is `Double`.

So, in your class, you simply call the interface `.sum()` to sum up your two numbers, and you leave the implementation details (the `a + b`, basically) to the concrete implementation which is not done by you, but by Java itself in the JDK's classes that extend `Number`.

Comment: I’m still learning Java so forgive my ignorance, but where exactly is the override for the method sum? How is the sum method being initialized?

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 when I initialize the StackArrayList<Double>, I pass the method reference "Double::sum". That's already an implementation of the same interface.

Comment: So the Double class has an implementation of an interface that contains a sum() method? And then that same sum() method is being transferred to the SumPerformer interface?

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 the Double class (as well as Long, Float, Integer..) have a method with signature N sum(N n1, N n2). They don't explicitly implement your interface, but the signature perfectly matches, so you can use it as a concrete implementation of your abstract interface.

Comment: Ah I see, didn’t know you can pass along methods like that to an interface if the methods have the same signatures. Thanks

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 the Override annotation is an optional annotation. It is very good practice to have it (many code smell tools will throw an error if it's missing), but it's not compulsory, the compiler relies just on the signatures matching. In your case, it comes handy.

Comment: Matteo NNZ, i understand it now and it is just Genius doing such a thing :D 
The thing i don't understand now is with the initialization from this class where i have to put "sum" also in the constructor, along with the variable ? Doesn't the Variable need to be inside the <> ? is there a special name for this kind of trick wich i can google up to learn about it to understand it ? :)

Comment: Edit:  new StackArrayList<>(Double::sum); <<< i mean this bad boy here. 
I can see that u are doing it over a Constructor, so shouldnt it just pass down the Number i initialize the Object with ?

Comment: also i cannot really see where you are adding those 2 together to a Sum with a + , where does that happen ? Sorry for all the Questions.

Comment: @DavidRumpf it's not genius, it's just Java :) I've updated the answer with the answers to your comments, let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ okay, i think i can follow it now.  But i dont get the Syntax 
`StackArrayList<Double> stackArrayListDoubles = new StackArrayList<>(Double::sum);`
the last part, why is it written like that (Double::sum). With the 2 colon, is there a name for it wich i can google up to learn about it ?

Comment: @DavidRumpf yes, there is a name for that syntax, it's called [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)